# How to get the canvas visible when the textbox gets focus?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, keyboard, sip

I have added a `Canvas` to the `Grid` then added my custom keypad on the canvas. Now on `TextBox.GotFoucs` event I changed `Canvas.Visibilty = Visiblity.Visible;`

But the issue is that when the `TextBox` gets focus it shows the default keypad in front and my `Canvas` behind it. I want the `Canvas` to be displayed on top of the default keypad and should work as a text entry control to the `TextBox`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display of the SIP is handled by the operating system and will always be on top of the visual tree of any application. If you want to provide a custom SIP, you will need to provide an alternative input control, because the display of the native SIP is tied to input controls (such as `TextBox`, `PasswordBox`, etc.). You may find this article about [creating a Bulgarian keyboard](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx) useful.

Comment: is there a way to focus the textbox and bring canvas to front.Or without focusing the textbox, can i get the cursor visibility and movement.

Comment: can u tell me that is there some api or custom textbox available where SIP is already.

Comment: In terms of adding custom SIPs, there is absolutely no support in the framework. The WP7-related keynote at MIX kicks off in about 20 minutes; if we're lucky they'll announce something then :) (I'm not holding out much hope for custom SIP support, though)